# agregar horas en modelos de Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, datetime

Estoy tratando de hacer un modelo de películas en Django, pero me gustaría agregarles la duración de la misma y esto no sé como hacerlo muy bien en Django, sé que se puede agregar fecha y hora con `datetime` en los modelos. Pero solo quiero una hora de duración.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/movies/')
    description = models.TextField()
    duration = models.CharField()
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genres)
    categorie = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
```

Tengo ese modelo, obviamente un `ChaField` en duración no me serviría porque aceptaría valores alfanuméricos y esa no es la idea.

Si alguno pudiese ayudarme a definir bien un formato para agregar horas lo apreciaría!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te presento al campo **`DurationField`** que sirve para almacenar periodos de tiempo según el objeto [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

Las precisiones las puedes encontar en la documentación de Django, dejo el enlace que corresponde a la version 1.10: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/models/fields/#durationfield

Comment: Excelente @toledano debería preguntarte a ti directamente las dudas de Django xD. El segundo párametro que recibe timedelta es en segundos y lo pasa en horas en el campo? Saludos!

Comment: No entendí, pero según la documentación, días, segundos y microsegundos se almacenan internamente y se normalizan, por ejemplo, si hay mas de 86,400 segundos, se suma uno a días y se resta esa cantidad de segundos.

Comment: Ok, ok, creo que más o menos entendí ese asunto. Muchas gracias por la ayuda :P